# How to display a RPM of a vehicle in xcode using some graphics

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I am new to xcode. This is my very first app. In this app i need to display the RPM of a vehicle and I get the RPM data from `JSON` service. But i don't know how to display it using graphically. Please advice me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is RPM? please be more clear

Comment: @BogdanSomlea RPM means Rotate per minute it is the speed calculator

Comment: and how do you want to display it graphically?

Comment: I want to display it something like speedometer..

Answer (score -1):

You want to show the RPM as a bar type graph? You can use UIView for this.

```
_graph = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 20)];
[_graph setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:_graph];
```

and RPM setting method:

```
- (void)setRPM:(NSInteger)rpm
{
    const NSInteger maxRPM      = 2000;
    const NSInteger maxWidth    = 200;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{

                     CGRect frame = _graph.frame;
                     frame.size.width = maxWidth * (rpm / maxRPM);
                     _graph.frame = frame;

                 }];
}
```

Now, you can change the bar size...

```
[self setRPM:1000]
```

What about this?

Comment: Sorry i can't get your answer correctly. Could you please explain more? else please give me some example download link Thank you..